# Match the context of MaybeT's Monad and Applicative: I actually found a counter-example

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

[I wonder if Applicative is derived naturally through MonadTransformer's Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76032068/i-wonder-if-applicative-is-derived-naturally-through-monadtransformers-monad)

I had a hard time finding out if MaybeT's Monad and Applicative have the same context. As you can see in the link above.

The meaning of "same context" is

```
f <*> a = do
          x <- f
          y <- a
          return (x y)
```

I found a counter-example for MaybeT.

```
f = MaybeT [Nothing] :: MaybeT [] (Int -> Int)
a = MaybeT [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing] :: MaybeT [] Int

f <*> a = [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]

do
x <- f
y <- a
return (x y)

= [Nothing]
```

So,
it seems like there's a discord in MaybeT's Applicative and Monad.

How could we mix up >> , *> , >>= . (<*>) if there is a discord?

I can't believe it.
If there is such a discrepancy, shouldn't there be a bug in the many Haskell codes currently using MaybeT?

Comment: oh ho ho.... I got it.... MaybeT's (<*>) is different from ```Compose m Maybe```!!! Why??

Comment: Yeah, `f <*> a` is actually only `[Nothing]` too. OTOH, `Compose [] Maybe` doesn't have a `Monad` instance at all.

Comment: In general, the composition of two monads is not always a monad. This is the reason why, as @leftaroundabout said, `Compose f g` doesn’t generally have a `Monad` instance, even when `f` and `g` are `Monad`s

Comment: In the book , Haskell programming from first principle, it says that <*> of ```MaybeT``` is same as ```Compose```'s applicative. It's wrong. I was confused about it. sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 4):

Quoting a comment:

> `MaybeT`'s `(<*>)` is different from `Compose m Maybe`

Indeed:

```
ghci> import Data.Functor.Compose 
ghci> import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe 
ghci> f = MaybeT [Nothing] :: MaybeT [] (Int -> Int)
ghci> a = MaybeT [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing] :: MaybeT [] Int
ghci> f <*> a
MaybeT [Nothing]
ghci> Compose (runMaybeT f) <*> Compose (runMaybeT a)
Compose [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
```

As for how they differ, `(<*>)` for `Compose` [is defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Compose.html#line-121):

```
Compose u <*> Compose v = Compose (liftA2 (<*>) u v)
```

*If* the two applicative functors being composed are also monads (as `[]` and `Maybe` are), we can express that in terms of their monad instances:

```
Compose (liftA2 (<*>) u v)

Compose $ do
    ui <- u  -- "i" is for "inner"
    vi <- v
    return (ui <*> vi)

Compose $ do
    ui <- u
    vi <- v
    return $ do
        f <- ui
        a <- vi
        return (f a)
```

Which, with the inner functor being `Maybe`, becomes:

```
Compose $ do
    ui <- u
    vi <- v
    return $ do
        f <- ui
        a <- vi
        Just (f a)
```

Whereas `(<*>)` for `MaybeT` is

```
mf <*> mx = MaybeT $ do
    mb_f <- runMaybeT mf
    case mb_f of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just f  -> do
            mb_x <- runMaybeT mx
            case mb_x of
                Nothing -> return Nothing
                Just x  -> return (Just (f x))
```

Let's rephrase the right-hand side in a style closer to the one above:

```
MaybeT u <*> MaybeT v = MaybeT $ do
    ui <- u
    case ui of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just f  -> do
            vi <- v
            case vi of
                Nothing -> return Nothing
                Just x  -> return (Just (f x))
```

`(<*>)` for `Compose` runs the outer effects before the inner ones, and so in your example you get the usual list `(<*>)` at the outer level, obtaining a list of 1 * 3 = 3 elements. `(<*>)` for `MaybeT`, however, runs the effects of its first argument (both the outer and the inner `Maybe`) before moving on to the second one, and that only if a `Just` is obtained, and so the `Nothing` lying in `f` in your example gives rise to merely another `Nothing`, resulting in `[Nothing]` overall.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the question has a false premise. The two expressions in the question,

```
f <*> a
```

and

```
do
  x <- f
  y <- a
  return (x y)
```

both produce the same result, `MaybeT [Nothing]`.

You shouldn't be able to find examples in the wild where these two expressions differ for a single type. One of the [laws listed in the Monad class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) is

```
m1 <*> m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= (\x2 -> return (x1 x2)))
```

which is just a desugaring of the identity you're trying to disprove. There are probably some examples out there of monads that break this law, but they're not "supposed" to.